# $f_k \to f$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ implies that its Fourier transform converges uniformly, i.e. $\hat{f}_k \to \hat{f}$ uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: uniform-convergence, fourier-transform

Assumme $f_k \to f$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and show that its Fourier transform converges uniformly, i.e. $\hat{f}_k \to \hat{f}$ uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$. Using the definiton and triangle inequality for integral, we obtain
\begin{align}
|\hat{f}_k(\xi) - \hat{f}(\xi)| \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}}|e^{-ix\xi}||f_k(x)-f(x)|\ dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_k(x)-f(x)|\ dx.
\end{align}
If I can just interchange the limit and the integral sign, then I believe I'm done because our bound is independent of $\xi$. In order to be able to do to that, I need dominated convergence theorem. But I have no idea how to find an integrable function $g$ such that $|f_k(x)-f(x)| \leq |g(x)|$. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the meaning  of $f_k$ converging to $f$ in $L^{1}$?

Comment: I think it means that $f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$ and $f \in L^1$. Or you mean the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of convergence?

Comment: It means $\int |f_k(x)-f(x)|dx \to 0$.

Comment: Ah really? well I must say that I didn't know that, thank you.